# pub get failed error with image_editor_pro

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to edit images such as crop and filter functionalities. I found this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro

I get this error while installing this package and its dependencies.

```
Cannot open file, path = 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\_temp\dir5ba449a4\test\fixtures\invalid\n_structure_<.>.json' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)
pub finished with exit code 66
```

I have tried everything based on previous answers related such as

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

Here is the pubspec.yaml

```
name: application_editing
description: A new Flutter project.


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.20.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  zoom_widget: ^0.1.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  permission_handler: ^7.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  screenshot: ^0.3.0
  signature: ^4.0.2
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.4.0
  firexcode: ^1.0.5

  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
  collection: ^1.15.0

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.9.2

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Also deleting pub cache folder. Nothing worked. The issue comes only when I install this image_editor_pro plugin. It is not the case with any other plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have added the wrong package, or the image URL which you added in your assets doesn't exist.

Comment: All the other packages are correctly added, there is no error in the code. The problem is only with image_editor_pro package. I am not able to install the package pub get only.

Comment: @Malay I have posted your request as a comment and it was answered by the OP. Please see the edited question

Comment: Ya I see, I tried to add it to my project and I am getting the same error. When I went to their Github page and when I go to issues, I see that there are more people facing this same error. I think it is a bit outdated and you will be able to use this after they fix it in their next update! @Mahi9